# Flask-MySQL gives "closing a closed connection" error the second time a view runs

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python

I am using Flask-MySQL to connect to my database in a view.  The view works the first time I go to it, but when I go to it the second time it always crashes with the error:

```
ProgrammingError: closing a closed connection
```

Why am I getting this error?  How do I connect successfully the second time?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'xxx'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'pies'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

    query = request.form['yourname']

    mysql = MySQL(app)
    conn = mysql.connect()

    with conn as cursor:
         try:
             cursor.execute(query)
             name = str(cursor.fetchone())
         except:
             name = "SQL is wrong"

    conn.close()
    return render_template('form_action.html', name=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `with conn as cursor:`?  That seems a strange way of using a context manager.

Comment: It was something I was tried to get rid of the problem, but obviously it did not work. The problem was there before adding "with conn as cursor:"

Comment: Is there a complete error traceback available anywhere that would indicate exactly which line of code is causing the error?  Perhaps in the web server error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be initializing the extension during every request.  Create it during app setup, then use it during the requests.  Setting configuration should also be done during app setup.

The extension adds a [teardown function](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/blob/2204ed2f3455bb89c5c86aa920c4174cefb5ecbb/flaskext/mysql.py#L26) that executes after every request and [closes the connection](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/blob/2204ed2f3455bb89c5c86aa920c4174cefb5ecbb/flaskext/mysql.py#L53), which is stored as a threadlocal.  Since on the second request you've registered the extension multiple times, it is trying to close the connection multiple times.

There's no need to call `connect`, the extension adds a [before request function](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/blob/2204ed2f3455bb89c5c86aa920c4174cefb5ecbb/flaskext/mysql.py#L27) that [does that](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/blob/2204ed2f3455bb89c5c86aa920c4174cefb5ecbb/flaskext/mysql.py#L48).  Use [`get_db`](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/blob/2204ed2f3455bb89c5c86aa920c4174cefb5ecbb/flaskext/mysql.py#L55) to get the connection for the request.  Since the extension closes this connection for you, don't call `close` either.

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

MYSQL_DATABASE_USER = 'root'
MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
MYSQL_DATABASE_DB = 'pies'
MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/hello/')
def hello():
    conn = mysql.get_db()
    # ...
```

---

Note that Flask-MySQL is using a *very* old extension pattern that is no longer supported by Flask.  It also depends on an unsupported mysql package that does not support Python 3.  Consider using Flask-MySQLdb instead.